# sort two dimensional array of objects based on name or sort array of array of objects based on name

Tags: javascript, sorting, multidimensional-array

```js
const input = [
  [
    { name: "d", age: 17, id: 111 },
    { name: "d", age: 12, id: 111 },
    { name: "d", age: 14, id: 111 },
    { name: "d", age: 11, id: 111 },
  ],
  [
    { name: "d", age: 17, id: 112 },
    { name: "d", age: 12, id: 112 },
    { name: "d", age: 14, id: 112 },
    { name: "d", age: 11, id: 112 },
  ],
  [
    { name: "b", age: 13, id: 113 },
    { name: "b", age: 11, id: 113 },
    { name: "b", age: 17, id: 113 },
    { name: "b", age: 15, id: 113 },
  ],
  [
    { name: "a", age: 12, id: 114 },
    { name: "a", age: 11, id: 114 },
    { name: "a", age: 16, id: 114 },
    { name: "a", age: 13, id: 114 },
  ],
  [
    { name: "a", age: 12, id: 115 },
    { name: "a", age: 11, id: 115 },
    { name: "a", age: 16, id: 115 },
    { name: "a", age: 13, id: 115 },
  ],
  [
    { name: "c", age: 19, id: 116 },
    { name: "c", age: 11, id: 116 },
    { name: "c", age: 15, id: 116 },
    { name: "c", age: 12, id: 116 },
  ],
];

// below should be required output for the above input 
`output`[
  [
    { name: "a", age: 12, id: 114 },
    { name: "a", age: 11, id: 114 },
    { name: "a", age: 16, id: 114 },
    { name: "a", age: 13, id: 114 },
  ],
  [
    { name: "a", age: 12, id: 115 },
    { name: "a", age: 11, id: 115 },
    { name: "a", age: 16, id: 115 },
    { name: "a", age: 13, id: 115 },
  ],
  [
    { name: "b", age: 13, id: 113 },
    { name: "b", age: 11, id: 113 },
    { name: "b", age: 17, id: 113 },
    { name: "b", age: 15, id: 113 },
  ],
  [
    { name: "c", age: 19, id: 116 },
    { name: "c", age: 11, id: 116 },
    { name: "c", age: 15, id: 116 },
    { name: "c", age: 12, id: 116 },
  ],
  [
    { name: "d", age: 17, id: 111 },
    { name: "d", age: 12, id: 111 },
    { name: "d", age: 14, id: 111 },
    { name: "d", age: 11, id: 111 },
  ],
  [
    { name: "d", age: 17, id: 112 },
    { name: "d", age: 12, id: 112 },
    { name: "d", age: 14, id: 112 },
    { name: "d", age: 11, id: 112 },
  ],
];
```

Hi, can anyone help me in the above case of two dimensional array of objects,
i want to get the above output as per NAME in SORTING ORDER based on that above input. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could compare each array-type-element by its first element's name

```
const res = input.sort((a,b) => a[0].name.localeCompare(b[0].name))
```

---

Implementation

```js
const input = [
  [
    { name: "d", age: 17, id: 111 },
    { name: "d", age: 12, id: 111 },
    { name: "d", age: 14, id: 111 },
    { name: "d", age: 11, id: 111 },
  ],
  [
    { name: "d", age: 17, id: 112 },
    { name: "d", age: 12, id: 112 },
    { name: "d", age: 14, id: 112 },
    { name: "d", age: 11, id: 112 },
  ],
  [
    { name: "b", age: 13, id: 113 },
    { name: "b", age: 11, id: 113 },
    { name: "b", age: 17, id: 113 },
    { name: "b", age: 15, id: 113 },
  ],
  [
    { name: "a", age: 12, id: 114 },
    { name: "a", age: 11, id: 114 },
    { name: "a", age: 16, id: 114 },
    { name: "a", age: 13, id: 114 },
  ],
  [
    { name: "a", age: 12, id: 115 },
    { name: "a", age: 11, id: 115 },
    { name: "a", age: 16, id: 115 },
    { name: "a", age: 13, id: 115 },
  ],
  [
    { name: "c", age: 19, id: 116 },
    { name: "c", age: 11, id: 116 },
    { name: "c", age: 15, id: 116 },
    { name: "c", age: 12, id: 116 },
  ],
]

const output = [
  [
    { name: "a", age: 12, id: 114 },
    { name: "a", age: 11, id: 114 },
    { name: "a", age: 16, id: 114 },
    { name: "a", age: 13, id: 114 },
  ],
  [
    { name: "a", age: 12, id: 115 },
    { name: "a", age: 11, id: 115 },
    { name: "a", age: 16, id: 115 },
    { name: "a", age: 13, id: 115 },
  ],
  [
    { name: "b", age: 13, id: 113 },
    { name: "b", age: 11, id: 113 },
    { name: "b", age: 17, id: 113 },
    { name: "b", age: 15, id: 113 },
  ],
  [
    { name: "c", age: 19, id: 116 },
    { name: "c", age: 11, id: 116 },
    { name: "c", age: 15, id: 116 },
    { name: "c", age: 12, id: 116 },
  ],
  [
    { name: "d", age: 17, id: 111 },
    { name: "d", age: 12, id: 111 },
    { name: "d", age: 14, id: 111 },
    { name: "d", age: 11, id: 111 },
  ],
  [
    { name: "d", age: 17, id: 112 },
    { name: "d", age: 12, id: 112 },
    { name: "d", age: 14, id: 112 },
    { name: "d", age: 11, id: 112 },
  ],
]

const res = input.sort((a,b) => a[0].name.localeCompare(b[0].name))

console.log(res)
```

Comment: @saikrishna but this answer already has the desired output, that you mentioned in your question...